# Always keep column width's equal in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I current have a WPF application that contains a `ListBox` of `Grid` items.

These grids have 2 columns each and the first column contains text and the second one contains an ellipse.

My issue is that I currently have both `ColumnDefinition` set to have width of `.5*` so they each take 50% of the total width. However, this doesn't work when the text is too long or else it pushes the ellipse in the second column out of line with the rest of the ellipses in the list (looking vertically from top to bottom).

Basically this is what I get:

[image]

What I would like to happen is have all of the elipses in-line no matter how long the text in the first column is.

I've tried placing the first column's text inside of a `ViewBox` to auto-size it but that doesn't seem to work either.

Here is the full XAML for the `DataTemplate`:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainTermServListGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="MainTermServMainRow"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TServer}" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Grid x:Name="OldPathGrid" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Stretch="Uniform">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0">
            <Run Text="Path: "/>
            <Run Text="{Binding OldPath}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>

        <Ellipse Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="{Binding ElementName=MainTermServListGrid, Path=ActualHeight}" Fill="{Binding IsOldPathValid, Converter={StaticResource ValPthToBgClr}}"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="NewPathGrid" Grid.Column="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0">
            <Run Text="Path: "/>
            <Run Text="{Binding NewPath}"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <Ellipse Grid.Column="1" Width="{Binding ElementName=MainTermServListGrid, Path=ActualHeight}" Fill="{Binding IsNewPathValid, Converter={StaticResource ValPthToBgClr}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: can you paste the datatemplate of the Listbox?

Comment: Added it to my main post @kanchirk

Comment: The ,5 it totally redundant. If you set the column widths to just "*" they will divide into 50% for each of the 2 columns

Comment: Hi @user2357446 I've answered below, if the answer helped solve you problem, could you please mark as accepted? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at `SharedSizeGroup`

Essentially:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItems}"
   Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     <Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ColA" Width=".5*" />
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     </Grid>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Using the `SharedSizeScope` and `SharedSizeGroup`, you can ensure columns / rows are the **same size** across **different grids** within the same **containing scope**

> NOTE: It doesn't have to be an `ItemsControl` any container using the attached property `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` will ensure that grids contained within will pay attention.